# How to convert SQL statement with sub query into HQL

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, nhibernate, hql

I have a relatively simple SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * From Occasion 
WHERE 
(Occasion.StateId = @StateId AND Occasion.EndTime < @EndTime) 
OR 
(
   Occasion.StateId = @StateId 
   AND 
   @StartTime < (SELECT TOP 1 Time FROM StartTime where Occasion.OccasionId = StartTime.OccasionId ORDER BY Time DESC)
)
```

But I have no idea how to convert this into HQL. I've made a number of attempts but have been unable to get this to work. I receive mostly compile time errors which means my syntax is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the relevant parts of my mapping file:

```
<id name="Id" column="OccasionId" type="guid">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>

<bag name="StartTimeCollection" lazy="false" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore" table="StartTime">
  <key column="OccasionId" />
  <element type="datetime2">
    <column sql-type="datetime2(7)" not-null="true" name="Time" />
  </element>
</bag>

<property name="EndTime" type="datetime2">
  <column name="EndTime" sql-type="datetime2(7)" not-null="false" />
</property>

<many-to-one not-null="true" lazy="false" fetch="join" name="_state" column="StateId" access="field" />

<property name="Status" formula="StateId" access="readonly" insert="false" update="false" />
```

```
<id name="Id" column="OccasionStateId">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>

<discriminator column="Name" type="string">
  <column name="Name" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" />
</discriminator>

<subclass name="PendingState" discriminator-value="Pending" />
<subclass name="StartedState" discriminator-value="Started" />
<subclass name="EndedState" discriminator-value="Ended" />
```

Comment: You write HQL base on your classes. So we cannot help you we we don't know the classes. Mapping information might also be important.

Comment: I have just edited the post to include the relevant parts of my hbm file.

Comment: By the way, this performs vary bad as soon as you have many items in StartTimeCollection or Occasion. Consider using an idbag to improve adding items to the list. Consider storing the max start time and probably the min start time in separate fields to improve finding occasions by this values. The state looks like an enum which actually doesn't belong to a table. You could avoid this formula stuff which tends to cause troubles. Guids are also a very bad choice for primary keys, and native as well. If you plan to store only a few thousand values, ignore me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your class model, so I have to guess.

Assuming that there is a onw-to-many relation Occasion to StartTime (which is only a list of primitive values of time):

```
From Occasion o
WHERE 
  (o.StateId = :StateId 
    AND o.EndTime < :EndTime)
  OR 
  (
     o.StateId = :StateId 
     AND :StartTime < max(elements(o.StartTimes))
  )
```

(TOP 10 is done with `.SetMaxresults(10)`.)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this and no longer receiving a compile time error but I am receiving the following run time error: 

InnerException = {"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.\r\nIncorrect syntax near ')'."}

Comment: Everything seems to work except for max(elements(o.StartTimeCollection))

Comment: What doesn't work? How does the SQL look like, which had been generated? Make sure to pass in the correct type of the parameter StartTime.

Comment: It generates the following SQL: 

@p1 < max ( select starttimec1_.Time from StartTime starttimec1_ where occasion0_.OccasionId=starttimec1_.OccasionId) 

Which errors where it says "max ( select" and also it doesn't know what occasion0_OccasionId is.

Comment: Could it possibly depend on the DB?

Comment: The solution was: maxelement(o.StartTimeCollection) so just update your answer to reflect this change.

Comment: maxelement is the last element in the collection. It is strange that it is actually working, since the bag doesn't have an order.